# How do I dismiss a modal view controller in the right side of splitViewController?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I present a modal view controller in the detail view of my splitViewController with the following code:

```
AddressViewController *addressViewController = [[AddressViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddressViewController" bundle:nil];
addressViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
addressViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:addressViewController animated:YES];
addressViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[addressViewController release];
```

But when I dismiss the  modal view controller, it flips so that it gets behind the master view controller for a short time. When the transition is over, it "jumps" to its right place.

Does somebody know how to prevent this?

Comment: What version of iOS were you on?  Have you tried without the set frame line?

Comment: I'm using iOS 4.3 and without the set frame line the modal view controller comes up over the whole screen